# Converting SRAM to another SRAM

Tags: cpu-architecture

How would I convert a 16K x 32 SRAM into a 64K x 8 SRAM? The 16K x 32 RAM module is a single unit that cannot be altered internally and is capable of address decoding, has tristate outputs, and read/write/and chip enable. Also only the memory read of the circuit has to be implemented.

Comment: user3309221, What is your EE course? What does 16K x 32 means (how wide are address and output buses)?

Comment: 16K x 32 means 14 bit address bus A0-A13 (2^14 = 16K) and 32 data lines. You want to use 2 additional address lines (A14-A15) to select a subset of 8 of the 32 data lines at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The 16K x 32 SRAM accepts a 14-bit address and produces a 32-bit value. However, the 64K x 8 SRAM accepts a 16-bit address and produces an 8-bit value. You can design a circuit whose interface exactly matches the interface of a 64K x 8 SRAM module. However, internally, it sends the most significant 14 bits of the supplied 16-bit address to the 16K x 32 SRAM together with the control signals. Then it uses the least significant 2 bits of the 16-bit address to select an 8-bit value from the 32-bit value produced by the 16K x 32 SRAM. Finally, the resulting 8-bit value is sent to the output pins of the circuit.